# Injecting multiple instances of different beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to solve a problem with the Spring DI. I have two beans (`MyFirstBean` & `MySecondBean`) that both implement a given interface (`MyBean`). Then I have multiple other beans (e.g. `OtherBean`) that I want to use with either one of the two beans. Autowiring obviously fails for `OtherBean` since there are multiple instances of `MyBean` to choose from. Is there any possibility to generically create two instances of each bean 
 that autowires `MyBean` and refer to them using qualifiers? I know this is possible by writing a configuration class but since all this is part of an API, I want to keep the overhead as low as possible.

**Current Situation:**

```
public interface MyBean {
}

@Component
public class MyFirstBean implements MyBean {
}

@Component
public class MySecondBean implements MyBean {
}

@Component
public class OtherBean {

    final MyBean myBean; // error due to multiple beans

    public OtherBean(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }
}
```

**Desired Situation:**

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    final OtherBean myBeanUsingFirstBean; // internally autowires MyFirstBean

    final OtherBean myBeanUsingSecondBean; // internally autowires MySecondBean

    public SomeBean(
        @FirstBeanQualifier OtherBean myBeanUsingFirstBean,
        @SecondBeanQualifier OtherBean myBeanUsingSecondBean) {
        this.myBeanUsingFirstBean = myBeanUsingFirstBean;
        this.myBeanUsingSecondBean = myBeanUsingSecondBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Annotate your bean class with the correct @Qualifier then autowire your beanss with the desired qualifier.

Comment: The subtle difference is hard to explain. I could add a qualifier to ```OtherBean``` and thus resolve the conflict. But then I'd need two beans ```OtherFirstBean``` which uses ```MyFirstBean``` and is annotated accordingly, and ```OtherSecondBean``` which uses ```MySecondBean```. This is not what I want. I want to use an annotation when autowiring ```OtherBean``` and decide which bean ```OtherBean```  uses internally...

Comment: How about a Processor( implementing a factory pattern) which will return you the right instance each time you ask it to do so?

Comment: Can the factory react to different qualifier annotations? How exactly would a solution look like?

Comment: @fynn Checkout my answer below

Comment: @fynn I am having this same problem, and I agree that there is a subtlety in your question that many of the answers are failing to capture.  The subtlety is that there is just one implementation of OtherBean, and you don't want to have two implementations (OtherBeanUsingFirstBean and OtherBeanUsingSecondBean), because all you really need is two instances of OtherBean (one with MyFirstBean injected, and the other with MySecondBean injected).  I haven't figured out how to solve this problem.  It's hard enough just to describe the problem.  But please let me know if you have solved it.

Answer (score 15):

### Solution 1 :

One of the ways spring autowires beans is by name. If not specified spring will create bean using class name (with small first letter) so for MyFirstBean , bean name will be myFirstBean. Knowing that you can autowire desired bean by changing the name of the property to final MyBean myFirstBean

```
public interface MyBean {
}

@Component
public class MyFirstBean implements MyBean {
}

@Component
public class MySecondBean implements MyBean {
}

@Component
public class OtherBean {

    // this way spring will inject instance of MyFirstBean
    @Autowired
    final MyBean myFirstBean ; 

}
```

### Solution 2 :

Sometimes i like to manually assign beans. So i autowire all available beans into list like so, and then later in @PostConstruct u do the logic :

```
@Autowired
private List<MyBean> myBeans;
```

### Solution 3 :

Using @Qualifier annotation

```
public interface MyBean {
}

@Component("fooBean")
public class MyFirstBean implements MyBean {
}

@Component
public class MySecondBean implements MyBean {
}

@Component
public class OtherBean {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fooBean")
    final MyBean myFirstBean ; 

}
```

### Solution 4:

Custom annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Target({
ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, 
ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyBeanType {
   String value();
}


public interface MyBean {
}

@MyBeanType("fooBean")
@Component()
public class MyFirstBean implements MyBean {
}

@MyBeanType("barBean")
@Component
public class MySecondBean implements MyBean {
}

@Component
public class OtherBean {

    @Autowired
    @MyBeanType("Foo")
    final MyBean myBean ; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the asker wants to avoid writing a Configuration class, I implemented a solution using one and I want to show that it's really not so bad.

Here is my Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextOtherBeanQualifier {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myFirstBean")
    private MyBean myFirstBean;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mySecondBean")
    private MyBean mySecondBean;

    // Here is how you get two different instances of OtherBean
    // while using the same implementation:

    @Bean
    public OtherBean otherBeanUsingFirstBean() {
        return new OtherBean(myFirstBean);
    }

    @Bean
    public OtherBean otherBeanUsingSecondBean() {
        return new OtherBean(mySecondBean);
    }
}
```

Now, you can fit this into your Desired Situation using the `@Resource` and `@Qualifier` annotations:

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("otherBeanUsingFirstBean")
    private OtherBean otherBeanUsingFirstBean; // internally autowires MyFirstBean

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("otherBeanUsingSecondBean")
    private OtherBean otherBeanUsingSecondBean; // internally autowires MySecondBean

}
```

Please try this out and let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add @Qualifier to your beans to distinguish between the different beans. When injecting the beans you can use the specified qualifier to inject the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If the code should look *exactly* like the OP has described, custom annotations will suffice:

```
@Qualifier("myFirstBean")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FirstBeanQualifier {}

@Qualifier("mySecondBean")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SecondBeanQualifier {}

@Component
public class OtherBean {
    private final MyBean myBean1;
    private final MyBean myBean2;

    public OtherBean(@FirstBeanQualifier MyBean myBean1,
                     @SecondBeanQualifier MyBean myBean2) {
        this.myBean1 = myBean1;
        this.myBean2 = myBean2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be the simplest thing one could do.

Create a processor requesting for an object of type MyBean

```
@Component
public class ProcessorFactory {

    @Autowired private MyFirstBean myFirstBean;
    @Autowired private MySecondBean mySecondBean;


    public MyBean getProcessor(arg) {
        if (arg == SomeValue1) {
            return myFirstBean;
        }else{
            return mySecondBean;
        }

    }
}
```

The usage class would look something like this

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceClass{
    @Autowired private ProcessorFactory processorFactory;
    //Other dependencies

    void doSomething(Some args){

        MyBean = processorFactory.getProcessor(arg);
       //Do something with the object

    }

}
```

Comment: This is an okay solution, but my problem with it is that it requires an additional argument to be passed to the doSomething method in order to call getProcessor to retrieve the needed implementation of MyBean.
I would prefer not having to change the method signatures of my SomeServiceClass.
Is there a way to create two different instances of SomeServiceClass, one where MyFirstBean has been injected, and one where MySecondBean has been injected?

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés See if overriding `getProcessor` can help you. [Warning] This is a BAD approach